# F# seems slower than other languages... what can I do to speed it up?

Tags: performance, f#, benchmarking

I like F# ; I really, really do. Having been bitten by the "functional programming"-bug, I force myself to use it when I have the opportunity to. In fact, I recently used it (during a one week vacation) to [code a nice AI algorithm](http://users.softlab.ntua.gr/~ttsiod/score4.html).

However, my attempts so far (see a SO question related to my first attempt [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850243/fsharp-runs-my-algorithm-slower-than-python)) seem to indicate that, though undoubtedly beautiful... F# has the slowest execution speed of all the languages I've used.

Am I doing something wrong in my code?

I verbosely explain what I did in my [blog post](http://users.softlab.ntua.gr/~ttsiod/score4.html), and in my experiments, I see OCaml and the rest of the group running anywhere from 5x to 35x faster than F#.

Am I the only one with such experiences? I find it disheartening that the language I like the most, is also the slowest one - sometimes by far...

**EDIT**: Direct GitHub link, [where the code lives](https://github.com/ttsiodras/Score4) in various language forms...

**EDIT2**: Thanks to Thomas and Daniel, speed improved considerably:

- Greatest speed boost: moving from "ref" to "mutable" gave a whopping 30%.
- Removing exceptions and using while/flagChecks gave another 16%.
- Switching from discriminated unions to enums gave another 5%.
- "inline" gave 0.5-1%

**EDIT3**: Dr Jon Harrop joined the fight: 60% speedup, by making ScoreBoard operate directly on the "enumerated" version of the data. The imperative version of F# now runs 3-4 times slower than C++, which is a good result for a VM-based runtime. I consider the problem solved - thanks guys!

**EDIT4**: After merging all optimizations, these are the results (F# reached C# in imperative style - now if only I could do something about functional style, too!)

- real    0m0.221s: That was C++
- real    0m0.676s: That was C# (imperative, C++ mirror)
- real    0m0.704s: That was F# (imperative, C++ mirror)
- real    0m0.753s: That was OCaml (imperative, C++ mirror)
- real    0m0.989s: That was OCaml (functional)
- real    0m1.064s: That was Java (imperative)
- real    0m1.955s: That was F# (functional)

Comment: I think your question is a good one but needs a more positive question-like title. Maybe something like "F# seems slower than other languages. How can I speed it up?"

Comment: I agree with @Zan. Your question seems to be a rant in its current state.

Comment: I think that the question still feels more like a rant. You reference a blog post, but it's unlikely that someone would read a long post in order to answer your question. Could you refine the question and find one particular piece of code that is slower in F# and that is short enough to fit into a question?

Comment: I fear that that's the point - it's not microbenchmarks that triggered my post, it's the fact that once you get down to it and write a complete algorithm, you find out that it runs a lot slower than what you'd expect from a compiled language. I've seen it twice so far, and the first time, Jon Harrop found a solution - I'm sort of hoping for a cameo...

Comment: In case it helps, I added a link to the GitHub repos where both the functional and imperative forms of the F# implementation can be seen.

Comment: @ttsiodras - Well, how did Jon Harrop find the solution in the first case? I assume he bechmarked the program and found the bottle-neck. Then he replaced the slow part with something faster. To ask a question, you need either a reasonably sized code sample (that someone can benchmark) or know what the bottle-neck is (so that someone can advise on more efficient approach).

Comment: The bottleneck is the "ScoreBoard" function (85% of the execution time), which I first implemented in functional style, and got an execution time of ...a minute. I then rewrote it in imperative form, which is shared in the two F# implementations (abminimax in functional/imperative) - but even when going all imperative, my F# code runs at half the speed of C# ... And you can benchmark - just checkout from GitHub and run "make benchmark"

Comment: from taking a quick look at your code, it seems that you are using the List module everywhere, doing multiple iterations of it, mapping, etc. i think you would find some improvements if you tried to use the Seq instead, also, for readability, you should probably break up your functions into smaller chunks

Comment: @ttsiodras: Your C++ code uses the `board` array in-place whereas your F# implementation copies it unnecessarily in the inner loop. You are also using arrays like `[|(0,0); (1,1); (2,2); (3,3)|]` that are obviously pointless. Fixing these obvious discrepancies immediately makes the F# almost 2× faster than before.

Comment: @Jon: (1) What do you mean "copies it in the inner loop"? Just in case you reviewed the wrong code, the comparison must be made with "F#/score4.fs", not "F#/score4_functional.fs" - where indeed there exists list processing (though I am not sure that implies copying - and even if it does, the same code (line by line!) runs 4x-5x under OCaml...)  (2) The arrays you are referring to exist under C++ too, so I don't understand what you mean... Can you send me the code after your fixups, so I can see the differences you refer to?

Comment: @Tomas: I am sad you decided to close this question - I don't understand why you consider it "not real", since it includes code and reproducible benchmarks, and it has already triggered responses with real speed benefits... If nothing else, 5 people so far have considered it a favorite question...

Comment: @ttsiodras: I agree that your question has merit, but it probably fits better at http://codereview.stackexchange.com since the "answer" would consist of iterative and systematic improvements to your code, not a single, definitive response.

Comment: @ttsiodras: Your `scoreBoard` function accesses `board` directly in your C++ but copies it into a new heap-allocated `scores` array in your F# and OCaml, requiring 1,300,000 unnecessary allocations totalling around 100Mb of space! You even commented on this difference between the programs yourself in your C++ code.

Comment: Temporary blindness - indeed, 60% speedup! Commited to github, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unless you can give a reasonably sized code sample, it's difficult to tell. Anyway, the imperative F# version should be as efficient as the imperative C# version. I think one approach is to benchmark the two to see what is causing the difference (then someone can help with making that bit faster).

I briefly looked at your code and here are some assorted (untested) suggestions.

- You can replace discriminated union `Cell` with an enum (this means you'll use value types and integer comparison instead of reference types and runtime type tests):

  ```
  type Cell =    
    | Orange = 1
    | Yellow = 2
    | Barren = 3
  ```
- You can mark some trivial functions as `inline`. For example:

  ```
  let inline myincr (arr:int array) idx =
    arr.[idx] <- arr.[idx] + 1
  ```
- Don't use exceptions for control-flow. This is often done in OCaml, but .NET exceptions are slow and should be only used for *exceptions*. You can replace the `for` loop in your sample with a `while` loop and a mutable flag or with a tail-recursive function (a tail-recursive function is compiled into a loop, so it will be efficient, even in imperative solution).

Comment: Tried the discriminated to enum: it gave a 5% speedup. Unexpected, thanks! Inlining didn't seem to help in any place I tried it... Will try removing the exception and report back.

Comment: Removing exceptions improved speed by another 16%. Imperative F# is now 60% slower than C#. Anything else I can try?

Comment: Following a suggestion from @Daniel thru chat, I moved from using "ref" to using "mutable" - and got another 10%. I am feeling positively hopeful - anything else, guys?

Comment: I was wrong - the speedup was in fact 30% when I moved from "ref" to "mutable" (already commited on GitHub). Wow, imperative F# is now at only 25% distance from C#... I consider it good enough.

Answer (score 12):

This isn't an answer, per se, but have you tried writing the *exact same* code in F# and C#, i.e., imperative F# code? The speed should be similar. If you're comparing terse functional code with heavy use of higher-order functions, sequence expressions, lazy values, complex pattern matching, etc.--all things that allow for shorter, clearer (read, more maintainable) code--well, there is frequently a trade-off. Generally, development/maintenance time is much greater than execution time, so it's usually considered a *desirable* trade-off.

Some references:
[F# and C# 's CLR is same then why is F# faster than C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857262/f-and-c-s-clr-is-same-then-why-is-f-faster-than-c)
[C# / F# Performance comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144227/c-f-performance-comparison)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142985/is-a-program-f-any-more-efficient-execution-wise-than-c

Another point to consider: in a functional language you're working at a higher level and it becomes very easy to overlook the costs of operations. For example, `Seq.sort` seems innocent enough, but naive use of it can doom performance. I'd recommend poring over your code, asking yourself along the way if you understand the cost of each operation. If you're not feeling reflective, a faster way to do this is, of course, with a profiler.

Comment: Actually, I did - if you go to my "Moving to imperative style" section in the blog post, you'll see that once I coded in C# (and got a 2x over F#) I re-wrote in imperative style for both OCaml and F#. F# remained well behind C# (6 seconds vs 3 seconds, a 2x). Not to mention that OCaml had 1.4 and C++ had 0.2 seconds...

Comment: I'd like to see your imperative F# code. There's no reason it should perform much different than C#.

Comment: By all means - as said in the blog post, the code lives in GitHub: https://github.com/ttsiodras/Score4/tree/master/ - navigate in the F# folder, it contains both the imperative and functional solutions.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I'm lazy, I'm not reading a _long_ blog post. ;-) Thanks for the link.

Comment: OK, the first red flag I see is `printf`. Get rid of it. It uses reflection and is S-L-O-W.

Comment: It is only called 7 times... it can't explain the difference in execution time.

Comment: @ttsiodras let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1747/discussion-between-daniel-and-ttsiodras)

Comment: Your suggestion for moving from "ref" to "mutable" turned out to be the best - thanks!

Comment: @ttsiodras: Cool. I'd still recommend profiling until it's on par with C#. There must be a reason for the difference. [Here](http://eqatec.com/Profiler/Download.aspx) is a free one.

Comment: In case you care about the final results: if you checkout from GitHub, after many optimizations, I now get: 
(real    0m0.221s: That was C++) (real    0m0.676s: That was C#  imperative) (real    0m0.704s: That was F# imperative) (real    0m0.753s: That was OCaml imperative) (real    0m0.989s: That was OCaml functional) (real    0m1.064s: That was Java imperative) (real    0m1.955s: That was F# functional)... So F# imperative reached C# imperative. Wish I could do something about the functional version, too :-)