# Pattern Match in F# much slower than If else / switch in C#?

Tags: c#, performance, f#, pattern-matching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [F# seems slower than other languages… what can I do to speed it up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794138/f-seems-slower-than-other-languages-what-can-i-do-to-speed-it-up)

I am a bit curious about the performance of pattern match, so I did the following test:

`poolEven` contains 10000 elements of 0,1,2,3, (2500 equal)

`testSize = 100000`

`IfelseEven(100000)`  takes 650ms (switch would be faster but I didn't attach the code) while `MatchEven(100000)` takes 7000ms that's 10x time

Does the performance degradation come from `Array.Fold`? I am 100% sure that if I go for `IEnumerable.Aggregate` the speed would greatly decrease. **But I thought F# handled `Array.Fold` better than C# with `IEnumerable.Aggregate`**.  I want to compare performance of most common (equivalent) ways of coding in 2 languages but not rigid ways to make them identical.

The tests are done in x64 release, with 10+ trials taken average with proper warm up

C#:

```cs
public void IfelseEven(int testSize)
{
    Ifelse(testSize, poolEven);
}

void Ifelse(int testSize, int[] pool)
{
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < testSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < poolCapacity;j++ )
        {
            var item = pool[j];
            if (item == 0)
            {
                sum += 5;
            }
            else if (item == 1)
            {
                sum += 1;
            }
            else if (item == 2)
            {
                sum += 2;
            }
            else if (item == 3)
            {
                sum += 3;
            }
            else
            {
                sum += 4;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void MatchEven(int testSize)
{
    PatternMatch.myMatch(testSize, poolEven);
}
```

F#:

```ml
module PatternMatch

let mat acc elem =
    acc +
    match elem with
    | 0 -> 5L
    | 1 -> 1L
    | 2 -> 2L
    | 3 -> 3L
    | _ -> 4L

let sum (pool:int[])=
    Array.fold mat 0L pool;

let myMatch testSize pool=
    let mutable tmp = 0L
    for i=0 to testSize do
        tmp <- sum(pool) + tmp
    tmp
```

Comment: Why dont you try the C# side with the same F# code, ie use Aggregate/Fold (on both sides)?

Comment: I dont know F#, but the `Fold` should be easy to convert to a loop.

Comment: Also: why are you calling `sum(pool)` on every loop? I dont see anything in `pool` changing.

Comment: @leppie yes switch is faster. Why i don't use Aggregate is because I want to compare performance of most common ways (equivalent) of coding in 2 languages but not exactly identical ways.  sum(pool) is used for more loops... cus it is too fast for each 10000 iterations.

Comment: As you can see, there is a significant performance penalty on 'tight' (do they even need to be tight with today's big CPU caches?) loops using higher-order functions (as with `Array.Fold`). Changing that to a simple tail recursive loop (and you dont even need to change that many characters) would be trivial, and would likely bring the performance within par (you can even try adding `inline`).

Comment: @colinfang That's an interesting comparison then, but it doesn't isolate pattern matching versus if/else.

Comment: `match` compiles to the same branching instructions as `if`/`else`. Any perceived difference is due to something else in your code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Voting to close—we could play this game all day long. For more commentary on why different code might have different execution times see [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794138/f-seems-slower-than-other-languages-what-can-i-do-to-speed-it-up). If you just want to speed up your F# function, try this:

```ml
let ifElse testSize (pool: _[]) = 
  let mutable sum = 0L
  for i = 0 to testSize - 1 do
    for j = 0 to pool.Length - 1 do
      match pool.[j] with
      | 0 -> sum <- sum + 5L
      | 1 -> sum <- sum + 1L
      | 2 -> sum <- sum + 2L
      | 3 -> sum <- sum + 3L
      | _ -> sum <- sum + 4L
  sum
```

By my measurements this handily licks the C# function (and it's still shorter and more readable):

C# 5655
F# 4003

Incidentally, leppie nailed it in the comments. I profiled your code and 78% of the time was spent in `Array.fold`—not good in a tight loop.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in the comments, by using an entirely different pattern, you are not really getting a comparison of `match` vs `if/elseif` in isolation.  Comparison of loops vs fold vs recurse is an entirely different question.

Using a more direct comparison (loops, same as Daniel's response), I got below results.  Release build, .NET 4.5, x64 target arch.

- C# and F# `if\elseif` approaches run pretty much exactly the same (in this contrived example).
- F# `match` was consistently faster than `if\elseif` in either
  language (in this contrived example)
- C# `switch` was consistently fastest (in this contrived example).